# pulseaudio stops working after hibernation

Tags: debian, pulseaudio, hibernate

I'm using Debian-Jessie, when I set my laptop to hibernate mode some processes would be suspended as expected, but after I start it again "pulseaudio" process don't work anymore and when I try to play some music or video using any media player like VLC, SMPlayer, etc. they crash!

I checked pulseaudio status as current user:

```
pulseaudio --check
echo $?
```

it returns the value 0, so it seems ok!

when I try to kill pulseaudio and start it over again nothing would happen:

```
pulseaudio --kill
pulseaudio --start
```

I try to do the same using SYSKILL signals, still nothing will change and crashes occur:

```
ps aux | grep pulseaudio
sudo kill 914
pulseaudio --start
```

and here are logs related in syslog:

```
rtkit-daemon[915]: Successfully made thread 6881 of process 6881 (/usr/bin/pulseaudio) owned by '1000' high priority at nice level -11.
```

dmesg:

```
[ 9903.006551] sound hdaudioC1D3: hda-codec: out of range cmd 3:5:707:ffffffff
```

I still don't know what's wrong with sound card or audio system; is it possible that the problem comes from another daemon? I don't want to restart my system each time it hibernates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found the answer, this problem comes from pulseaudio feature called "auto spawning process"

each time pulseaudio daemon stops working and there is no process, it will try to automatically spawn a process, so we need to stop it by the following way:

```
cp /etc/pulse/client.conf ~/.config/pulse/
vim ~/.config/pulse/client.conf
```

then uncomment the line which says "autospawn = yes" by removing the leading semicolon and change it to "autospawn = no" then save it.

now try to restart pulseaudio

```
pulseaudio --kill
pulseaudio --start
```

everything is fine now!